# Push Notification restrictions

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there any limits/restrictions about amount of notifications sent to the APNS in time range?
For example - can I send 100,000 messages for 100,000 devices (one message for one device) in one hour to notify them about new content available to purchase via in-app purchases ?
Found nothing about any restrictions in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a restriction for number of messages sent in a time frame. But I guess in your case, it is unclear, if it violates rules stated in *review guidelines* 5.6 and 5.8

> 5.6 Apps cannot use Push Notifications to send advertising, promotions, or direct marketing of any kind
>
> 5.8 Apps that excessively use the network capacity or bandwidth of the APN service or unduly burden a device with Push Notifications will
> be rejected

Comment: spamming about new content to purchase is definitely a violation of 5.6

Comment: Ok @coneybeare, but how about situation when for example user in his app subscribes some developer's applications feed and want to know when he will submit something new? Do you have some experience in similar case?